# Not able to install/remove/update any apps after I installed mssql-mlservices-mlm-r

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 20.04: After I installed SQL Server RServices, I was not able to open "Setting", "Software Updater", and not able to install/remove/update any apps in terminal. The following is the error message. If you guys have any idea how to fix it? I also tried to reinstall the gnome-control-center. The terminal won't let me go and pops the same GLIBCXX_3.4.26 error message.

```
computer@user1:~$ sudo apt-get update
```

apt-get: /opt/mssql/mlservices/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/rhel/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)